Norm of the Exponential of a Scalar Multiple of a Matrix
Basically, the title. Suppose, we have some matrix (or operator) $A$ - can we relate $\left\lVert e^{A}\right\rVert_2$ to $\left\lVert e^{k A}\right\rVert_2$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$? More generally, although I suspect this wouldn't make a difference, can we relate $\left\lVert e^{At}\right\rVert_2$ to $\left\lVert e^{k A t}\right\rVert_2$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t$ is, for example, time? In this case, I assume that $A$ is time-invariant and that it has no special properties.

I think you can only say that $|e^{kA}|\le |e^A|^k$ for any $k\ge 1$ and other similar bounds for the other $k$

hmm @Exodd, is that sub-multiplicativity?

How would that work if $k$ is not an integer?
